# How to create Dynamic url rewrite in magento with config.xml

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite

I need to rewrite my url.
my current url is below.

http://example.com/milano_theme/magazine/index/archive

http://example.com/milano_theme/magazine/index/show

http://example.com/milano_theme/magazine/index/showarchive/o/1

these are my urls.

i want to replace to be like this

http://example.com/milano_theme/magazine_archive.html

http://example.com/milano_theme/magazine_show.html

http://example.com/milano_theme/magazine_showarchive_o_1.html

### i created rewrite in my magento config.xml

```
<rewrite>
    <archiveshow>
       <from><![CDATA[#^/archiveshow/#]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[/magazine/index/showArchive/o/]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </archiveshow>

    <magazine>
       <from><![CDATA[#^/magazine[\/]?$#]]></from>
     <to><![CDATA[/magazine/index/show/$1]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </magazine>

    <archive>
       <from><![CDATA[#^/archive[\/]?$#]]></from>
     <to><![CDATA[/magazine/index/archive/$1]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </archive>

</rewrite>
```

I know it's possible through admin.
but i want to change this by config.xml

how can i do this?